# How to deploy Angular App in Live Server (Digital Ocean)?

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment, nodemon

I've uploaded my app in Digital Ocean server but it seems it's not working properly, here's the link of my app http://138.68.21.3/pos/. Once you've entered in this address and when you refresh the page it says "Not Found" and "The requested URL `/pos/login` was not found on this server."

I don't know if my steps in deploying the angular app in live server are correct:

Step 1: I've typed `ng build --prod`

Step 2: Copied the files in **dist** folder and paste it in to root directory

Anyone who is expert in deploying angular app in live server? I need your help guys :(

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to use **useHash** in AppRoutingModule like this.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And also add

```
<base href="./"> instead <base href="/"> inside index.html
```

Hope this helps.

Ask me if any query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've already tried this solution but still no luck.

Comment: FYI, If you have created routing in nested folder...then you will have to make base: './nested_path/'